# Possible to paste into jsdoc comment in Visual Studio Code and have asterisks added to each line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Is there a way of pasting multiple lines of text into a jsdoc comment in Visual Studio Code and have asterisks added to each line? (Or more generally, of pasting into some sort of comment environment, whether line or block, and "doing the right thing"?)

Any relevant extensions?

I suspect that there is not built-in support, given that I can't see any relevant commands and [this issue] was closed for lack of interest and has not been linked to.

Comment: Same here. `@license` is always a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension `jsdoc-comment-toggler`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zachhardesty.jsdoc-comment-toggler&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).